# Set ImageView to bottom

Tags: android

Hi I am trying android and i am WP c# developer. So having a problem to set the image to the bottom middle of the screen. In WP it is quite easy for me. so here what i have attempted :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appLogo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In WP i just do it in a Grid and set VerticalAlignment = Bottom and done.

My mindset is not set for android right now so sorry for the very basic question.
any help and pointers are highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to put it in a RelativeLayout and then use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on your ImageView. Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/appLogo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yo dear :) great job.

Comment: Bro don't worry i will mark it right SO just not allowing me to do it too soon.